# is it possible to use AAG with two 2-Node Clusters across two datacenters?

Tags: availability-groups

Is the following scenario possible?

- 2-Node Automatic Failover Cluster in DC1, shared disk
- 2-Node Automatic Failover Cluster in DC2, shared disk
- employ a 'Node and Disk Majority'
- employ AAG across datacenters
- failover will be manual; availability mode asynchronous

The datacenters are up to 15.5-miles apart.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: From all your questions today so far (ONLY on AlwaysON), it seem to me that you should **really** readup on the basics of AlwaysON and clustering. That will help you becoming better at this new technology and ask more specific questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put, if you have, or can create, a Windows Server Failover Cluster setup across the data centres as a stretch cluster, then there is no reason why this is won't be possible. The fact the DC's are geographically dispersed is irrelevant. Good networking can bring them together as if they were not.

You could also do this as a SQL Cluster, with replication across the disks, and the disks presented to the cluster as a shared cluster resource.

I think you need to read up on the Pro's and Con's of each solution, and maybe speak to a Windows Server and/or Networking professional.